# cv2.lines() or any other drawing functions affects images above it?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

This piece of code is inside while loop and what i expect is to see the image without lines on it, as lines are applied to `img_roi` and not to `img_clone` but in the output image what i get is image with lines on it.

also, i want to detect lane if anyone can help with that it'd be great. Thank you.

```
ret, img_color = vid.read()

num_rows, num_cols = img_color.shape[:2]
rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((num_cols/2, num_rows/2), 270, 0.56)  #3
img_rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img_color, rotation_matrix, (num_cols, num_rows))


height, width = img_rotated.shape[:2]
img_resize = cv2.resize(img_rotated,(int(0.8*width), int(0.8*height)), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC) #2

img_roi = img_resize[10:842,530:1000]
img_clone = img_resize[10:842,530:1000]

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_roi,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #1

img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_gray,330,350, apertureSize = 3)   #4

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img_canny, 1, np.pi/180, 60, maxLineGap = 240)

for line in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(img_roi, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0), 3)


cv2.imshow('frame',img_clone)
cv2.imwrite('image.jpg', img_clone)
```

[Output of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0rzR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically both `img_roi` and `img_clone` are referring to the same numpy array `img_resize`. Of course not in the whole `img_resize` but to the sliced part only. This can be done if you display `img_resize` at the end (after the line creation) where you can see lines are applied to a subimage only.

You can refer [here](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html#Slice-views) among other places for an explanation.

The easiest way for me would be to add `.copy()` at the end of the array you want to be separated from the rest. In your case `img_clone`:

```
img_clone = img_resize[10:842,530:1000].copy()
```

which will create an independent numpy array to have as the original image.